# Tikz flowchart: text vertical position inside node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In a TikZ flowchart, is it possible to tune precisely the position of the text of a node ?
For horizontal position, you can get out (mostly) with `align={left|center|right}`, but I can't seem to find something for the vertical position.

Reference: TikZ manual 3.0.1a, §17.4.3: Text Parameters

While this seems useless in case of simple nodes, I want to do that for a "bounding box" nodes, produced using "fit".

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit}
\begin{document} 

\tikzset{
    block/.style={
        rectangle, draw, fill=blue!10, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners
    }
}

\tikzset{
    container/.style={
        draw, rectangle, dashed, inner sep=3em
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm]
    \node [block] (b1) {Hello};
    \node [block,right of=b1] (b2) {World};
    \node[container,fit=(b1) (b2)] (cont1) {Caption};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As such, the "caption" text appears at the center of the node. How can I position it, say, bottom-center of the box ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a seperate node for the caption, set an anchor for it and position it on an anchor of the container node.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit}
\begin{document} 

\tikzset{
    block/.style={
        rectangle, draw, fill=blue!10, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners
    }
}

\tikzset{
    container/.style={
        draw, rectangle, dashed, inner sep=3em
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm]
    \node [block] (b1) {Hello};
    \node [block,right of=b1] (b2) {World};
    \node[container,fit=(b1) (b2)] (cont1) {};
    \node[anchor=south] at (cont1.south) {Caption};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks pretty good! So I assume I can't get away without a additional node. But I can handle that ! ;-)

Comment: @kebs I don't know of a way to do this without an additional node. But this is easy to use and with more nodes you can set some text in different positions (bottom, top and/or edges/sides, inside and/or outside of the container node).

Comment: or just as an inner label for the container node: `\node[container, fit=(b1) (B2), label={[anchor=south]below:Caption} (cont1) {};`

Comment: @Ignasi Just tried, that seems ok too (except for a missing ']'), consider adding as an answer ?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit}
\begin{document} 

\tikzset{
    block/.style={
        rectangle, draw, fill=blue!10, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners
    }
}

\tikzset{
    container/.style={
        draw, rectangle, dashed, inner sep=3em
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[]
    \node [block] (b1) {Hello};
    \node [node distance = 3cm,block,right of=b1] (b2) {World};
    \node[container,fit=(b1.base) (b2.base)] (cont1) {Caption};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** I misinterpreted the question (because I didn't read it carefully enough). I was misled by the fact that the "Caption" label was not aligned with the "Hello" and "World" boxes. I keep the above answer in case someone is wondering about the same thing. Like @Mike, I believe the simplest thing would be to add a node.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit}
\begin{document} 

\tikzset{
    block/.style={
        rectangle, draw, fill=blue!10, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners
    }
}

\tikzset{
    container/.style={
        draw, rectangle, dashed, inner sep=3em, 
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[]
    \node [block] (b1) {Hello};
    \node [node distance = 3cm,block,right of=b1] (b2) {World};
    \node[container,fit=(b1.base) (b2.base),text centered] (cont1) {};
    \node[above] at (cont1.south) {Caption};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but, no, not really. I'd expect the "caption" not to be on the same line as the two nodes, but below, near the bottom dashed line.

Comment: @kebs Apologies. I just stared at the picture and from this I guessed that you wanted to align the three texts.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome anyway! That happens to me sometimes too.

Answer (score 1):

By default, node contents is always vertically centered inside its area. I'm not 100% sure but I suppose that after node contents is fixed, the area is decided adding `xsep` and `ysep` margins. Therefore, if you want a non vertically centered node, it's better that you add some non visible text (with `phantom` or 0pt rules) above or below printed text.

Another option could be to use the `label` option. In fact a `label` is an independent node which is added after (`postaction`) the labelled node is drawn. Like in marmot's or Mike's solutions but with both commands compressed into one.

Default position for labels is the `north` anchor, but can be easily placed in other place just selecting the new position and label anchor.

In this particular case you should use a label defined with `label={[anchor=south]south:Caption}`, but following code shows some other examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit}
\begin{document} 

\tikzset{
    block/.style={
        rectangle, draw, fill=blue!10, 
        text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners
    },
    container/.style={
        draw, rectangle, dashed, inner sep=3em
    }   
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm]
    \node [block] (b1) {Hello};
    \node [block,right of=b1] (b2) {World};
    \node [container,fit=(b1) (b2),
        label={[anchor=south]south:Caption 1},
        label=Caption 2,
        label={[below right =5mm and 3mm]north west:Caption 3},
        label=center:Caption 4,
        ] (cont1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]